# How to include a query into another Query?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to specify the name of two movies and get the total count for the number of people who had seen those tow movies together , the inner select is working perfectly and gives me the total results of all movies in the DB but when I tried to put the outer select to specify only two movies I got syntax error , Any help please ??

```
 SELECT t.movie1,
        t.movie2,
        t.count 
 FROM t
 (SELECT I.Movie movie1,
         J.Movie movie2, 
         COUNT(I.CustomerId) count
 FROM Movies I, 
      Movies J 
 WHERE I.CustomerID = J.CustomerID 
       AND I.Movie < J.Movie
 GROUP BY I.Movie, 
          J.Movie
 HAVING COUNT(I.CustomerID) >= 150) as t
 WHERE movie1 LIKE 'Star Wars Episode II: Attack of the Clones' 
       AND movie2 LIKE 'Star Wars Episode V: Empire Strikes Back';
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify the alias twice; you select from t before you identify the inner query as t.

```
SELECT  t.movie1
      , t.movie2
      , t.count
FROM    ( SELECT    I.Movie movie1
                  , J.Movie movie2
                  , COUNT(I.CustomerId) count
          FROM      Movies I
                    JOIN Movies J ON I.CustomerID = J.CustomerID
                                     AND I.Movie < J.Movie
          GROUP BY  I.Movie
                  , J.Movie
          HAVING    COUNT(I.CustomerID) >= 150
        ) AS t
WHERE   movie1 LIKE 'Star Wars Episode II: Attack of the Clones'
        AND movie2 LIKE 'Star Wars Episode V: Empire Strikes Back';
```

Comment: but like this the count is zero and it should be 175

Comment: There shouldn't be any fundamental differences; I just prefer the JOIN syntax.  The big reason for your syntax error was the double placement of the "t" alias; if you wish, leave your inner query as is, and just fix the alias issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner query is fine, but you don't actually specify a table in the outer query. The best way to visualise this is to imagine everything inside the brackets is a tablename. Here is what you have written:

```
 SELECT t.movie1,
        t.movie2,
        t.count 
 FROM t
 t as t
 WHERE movie1 LIKE 'Star Wars Episode II: Attack of the Clones' 
       AND movie2 LIKE 'Star Wars Episode V: Empire Strikes Back';
```

Sometimes when you are struggling with joins like this it is easier to break your query up into two queries using a #tmp table.

```
DECLARE @MovieName1 VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @MovieName2 VARCHAR(500)
SET @MovieName1 = 'IT'
SET @MovieName2 = 'The Fly'

SELECT
    a.CustomerID,
INTO 
    #Movie1Users
FROM 
    Movies a
WHERE a.MovieName = @MovieName1

SELECT
    a.customerID,
    @MovieName1,
    @MovieName2,
    COUNT(*) AS CustomerCount
FROM 
    Movies a
    INNER JOIN #Movie1Users b ON a.customerID = b.CustomerID
WHERE 
    a.MovieName = @MovieName2

Drop table #Movie1Users
```

It then becomes a lot easier to see how this would work as one query. (I prefer to keep inner query alias names different to avoid confusion). Hopefully my syntax below will help you with future queries.

```
DECLARE @MovieName1 VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @MovieName2 VARCHAR(500)
SET @MovieName1 = 'IT'
SET @MovieName2 = 'The Fly'

SELECT
    @MovieName1,
    @MovieName2,
    COUNT(*) AS CustomerCount
FROM 
    Movies a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            z.CustomerID
        FROM 
            Movies z
        WHERE z.MovieName = @MovieName1
    )  b ON a.customerID = b.CustomerID
WHERE 
    a.MovieName = @MovieName2
```

Finally it is possible to write your query without a subquery:

```
DECLARE @MovieName1 VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @MovieName2 VARCHAR(500)
SET @MovieName1 = 'IT'
SET @MovieName2 = 'The Fly'

SELECT 
    @MovieName1 AS Movie1,
    @MovieName2 AS Movie2,
    (COUNT(*)/2) AS CustomerCount
FROM dbo.Movies a
INNER JOIN movies b ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
WHERE
    (a.MovieName = @MovieName1 AND b.MovieName = @MovieName2)
    OR (a.MovieName = @MovieName2 AND b.MovieName = @MovieName1)
GROUP BY a.CustomerID
```